# Can we delete template or envelop using php code api

Tags: docusignapi, documentation

My requirement is to delete tamplete or envelop when envelop sent or signed

can any provide me any documentetion or method how to delete tamplete or envelop

Thanks in adavance !

how to delete tamplete or envelop in docusin using php library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is PHP code to delete an an envelope from [this blog post](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/common-api-tasks-delete-and-undelete-envelope):

**Note** that the blog post was about envelopes, but the exact same code works to delete templates, just put the **tempalateIds** where I say to put the **envelopeIds**

Also, you can put more than one...

```
# Delete an envelope or template
$api_client = new \DocuSign\eSign\client\ApiClient($base_path);
$config = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Configuration($api_client);
# You will need to obtain an access token using your chosen authentication method
$config->addDefaultHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + $access_token);
$folders_api = new FoldersApi(config);
$envelope_id = '9e2b1deb-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-2540322a31c4';
$folder_request = new \DocuSign\eSign\model\FoldersRequest();
$folder_Request->setEnvelopeIds([$envelope_id]);
$folders_api->moveEnvelopes($account_id, 'recyclebin', $folder_request);
# Move the deleted envelope back to the Inbox folder
$folders_response = $folders_api->list($account_id);
# Search for the folders you are interested in
for ($folders_response->getFolders() as $folder)
{
    if ($folder->getName() == 'Inbox')
    {
        $inbox_folder_id = $folder->getFolderId();
    }
    elseif ($folder->getName() == 'Deleted Items')
    {
        $recycle_bin_folder_id = $folder->getFolderId();
    }
}
$folder_request->setFromFolderId($recycle_bin_folder_id);
$folder_request->setEnvelopeIds([$envelope_id]);
$folders_api->moveEnvelopes($account_id, $inbox_folder_id, $folder_request);
```

Answer (score 0):

**This code is work for me now**
$token = TokenModel::first();

```
    $config = new Configuration();
    $config->setHost(env('DOCUSIGN_BASE_URL'));
    $config->addDefaultHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' . $token['access_token']);
    

    
    # Delete an envelope or template
   
    $api_client = new ApiClient($config);
    $folders_api = new FoldersApi($api_client);
    # You will need to obtain an access token using your chosen authentication method
    $envelope_id = $template_id;
    $folder_request = new FoldersRequest();
    
    
    $folder_request->setEnvelopeIds([$envelope_id]);
    
    $folders_api->moveEnvelopes(env('DOCUSIGN_ACCOUNT_ID'), 'recyclebin', $folder_request);
    
    # Move the deleted envelope back to the Inbox folder
    $folders_response = $folders_api->callList(env('DOCUSIGN_ACCOUNT_ID'));
    $folders_response = $folders_response['folders'];
    foreach($folders_response as $folders_res){
        if($folders_res['name'] == 'Inbox'){
            $inbox_folder_id = $folders_res['folder_id'];
        }
        if($folders_res['name'] == 'Deleted Items'){
            $recycle_bin_folder_id = $folders_res['folder_id'];
        }
    }
    $folder_request->setFromFolderId($recycle_bin_folder_id);
    $folder_request->setEnvelopeIds([$envelope_id]);
    $folders_api->moveEnvelopes(env('DOCUSIGN_ACCOUNT_ID'), $inbox_folder_id, $folder_request);
```

This code is work for me in laravel

Thanks #Inbar Gazit